# How to convert CellInfo timestamp to actual date?

Tags: android, telephonymanager, cellinfo

I am using TelephonyManger.getAllCellInfo to gather information about nearby cells. I noticed that CellInfo contains a field named `mTimestamp`, which according to documentation is:

> Approximate time of this cell information in nanos since boot

Now, I want to convert this time to an actual timestamp, which will give me the specific date on which the sample was taken.

Is doing it as such: `return System.currentTimeMillis() - timestampFromBootInNano / 1000000L;` the correct way to convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `mTimestamp` is measured in nanoseconds since the device was booted. `System.currentTimeMillis()` is measured in milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970.

You can:

- Subtract `mTimestamp` from `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()`, to determine how many nanoseconds ago the timestamp represents
- Convert that to milliseconds to determine how many milliseconds ago the timestamp represents
- Subtract that from `System.currentTimeMillis()` to determine the time when the timestamp was made

So, that gives us:

```
long millisecondsSinceEvent = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - timestampFromBootInNano) / 1000000L;
long timeOfEvent = System.currentTimeMillis() - millisecondsSinceEvent;
```

`timeOfEvent` can now be used with things like `java.util.Calendar`, ThreeTenABP, etc.

Comment: Do you know if the CellInfo is constantly updated if the phone is stationary, meaning it stays in the same spot for some time? I noticed that every time I accessed the mTimestamp of CellInfo it was different every time.

Comment: @Keselme: I have not experimented much with this API. My gut instinct, though, matches what you see: it is updated frequently, based on signals received by in-range towers.